# C# html to pdf converter using wkhtmltopdf or any other free tools

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

What is the perfect tool for converting html to pdf in C# ?? I have found wkhtmltopdf through stackoverflow.com . But its not working . showing this message in time of converting "www.google.com" in command line.

> C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf>wkhtmltoimage.exe www.google.com go.pdf
>
> Loading page (1/2)
>
> Rendering (2/2)
>
> Error: Could not save image
>
> Done

I have also downloaded EO.pdf , but not sure how to use it through C# or command line.
Just want a simple tool and guideline in C# which can convert html to pdf from url or html soruce .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is that you are attempting to use `wkhtmltoimage.exe` to generate a PDF.  Use `wkhtmltopdf.exe` instead and you should be fine.

```
C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf>wkhtmltopdf.exe www.google.com go.pdf
```

As far as your question, I don't really believe that there is a perfect tool.  I have been *very* satisfied with wkhtmltopdf however.

Comment: indeed, wekhtmltopdf works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of [DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/). It's easy to integrate into web apps and can use C# to convert HTML to PDF or XLS format.

Here's a link showing how to [use it](https://docraptor.com/documentation#coding_examples)

Answer (score 0):

How about iText? http://itextpdf.com/